# Is there any way to manually trigger the "Resource Saver mode" in Docker desktop?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

As I understand it, "Resource Saver mode" is triggered automatically after a certain amount of time has elapsed without using any containers.

Is there a way to trigger this manually (without having to wait for the delay time)?

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use [Docker Pause](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/use-desktop/pause/).

At the time, there is no way to trigger the 'Resource Saver' manually, but the time is [configurable](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/use-desktop/resource-saver/).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between Pause and Resource Saver mode (other than you can trigger Pause manually) ...

Comment: According to the Docker Documentation above:

Resource Saver has higher precedence than the older Pause feature, meaning that while Docker Desktop is in Resource Saver mode, manually pausing Docker Desktop is not possible (nor does it make sense since Resource Saver actually stops the Docker Desktop Linux VM). In general, we recommend keeping Resource Saver enabled as opposed to disabling it and using the manual Pause feature, as it results in much better CPU and memory savings.